# From String to Struct Golang

Tags: string, performance, function, go

I created a function to transform a particular string (derived from [] bytes) into a struct. In the program I am building an encryption and a decryption are carried out and between these two passages the data are transferred via JSON. The function that I propose works, but at the time when the string becomes very long, processing times are very long.
What I would like to ask is if anyone has any idea how to speed up this function or how to manage the situation better.

this is the function

```
func Datadecrypt(input []byte) Data {

    s := string(input)

    vals := strings.Replace(s,"  "," ",-1)

    part := strings.Fields(vals)

    c := strings.Split(s, "int=")[1]
    co := strings.Split(c, ")")[0]

    count, err := strconv.Atoi(co)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var stringa string

    for j := 0; j<len(part); j++ {
        if strings.ContainsAny(part[j], ":") {
            stringa = stringa+" "+part[j]
        } else {
            stringa = stringa+","+part[j]
        }
    }

    var interpart []map[string]string
    var result Data

    var i = 0

    for {

        split := strings.Split(stringa, "[")[2+i]

        splitend := strings.Split(split, "]")[0]

        control := strings.Replace(splitend,"  "," ",-1)

        mapst := mapstring.StrToMS(control)

        interpart = append(interpart, mapst)

        i++

        if i >= count {
            break
        }
    }

    result = Data{Count: count, Results: interpart}

    return result
}
```

this is the struct

```
type Data struct {
    Count int `json:"count"`
    Results []map[string]string `json:"result"`
}
```

this is the string that derives from s: = string (input)

```
"Count=\"%!s(int=107)\"\nResults=\"[map[MATRICOLA:2 NOMEmy:value COGNOMEmy:value] map[MATRICOLA:7 NOMEmy:value COGNOMEmy:value] map[MATRICOLA:5 NOMEmy:value COGNOMEmy:value] map[MATRICOLA:6 NOMEmy:value COGNOMEmy:value]]\"\n"
```

The string I wrote above is printed using JSON response

This is the input string NOT JSON

```
Count="%!s(int=107)"
Results="[map[MATRICOLA:2 NOMEmy:value COGNOMEmy:value] map[MATRICOLA:7 NOMEmy:value COGNOMEmy:value] map[MATRICOLA:5 NOMEmy:value COGNOMEmy:value] map[MATRICOLA:6 NOMEmy:value COGNOMEmy:value]]"
```

this is the result I get through the function

```
{107 map[MATRICOLA:2 NOMEmy:value COGNOMEmy:value] map[MATRICOLA:7 NOMEmy:value COGNOMEmy:value] map[MATRICOLA:5 NOMEmy:value COGNOMEmy:value] map[MATRICOLA:6 NOMEmy:value COGNOMEmy:value]]}
```

Thanks, in advance

Comment: dont convert it to string, keep a byte slice instead, all functions are available https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/

Comment: What you are doing is converting the bytes to string and then working on the string to get the value is totally unnecessary.

Comment: Write a benchmark and use pprof to find what is slow.

Comment: Where does your string come from? File or http request? Maybe it would be better to use an io.Reader as input and not a string. Then you could parse the data with a bufio.Scanner

Comment: the string comes from a http request, but the response is encrypted.
It is read by ioutil.ReadAll and then decrypted with a decrypt function created by me and the result of all is the []byte in input in Datadecrypt().

Comment: As @Volker notes, you'll have to measure to find out what's slow, try optimizing, and measure to see if it's faster. That is the way to optimize code. Keep in mind though that encryption/decryption of large ciphertexts is going to take time no matter what (that's the point of encryption in a way), so there will be definite limits to how fast this can run.

Comment: you can also perform stream decoding https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder.Decode. It also exists libraries that are implemented with more efficient resulting algorithm for json decoding https://github.com/mailru/easyjson

Answer (score 0):

This is not a answer to your question, but maybe a solution to your problem. Just leave a comment if I am totaly wrong.

The input string looks like it is generated via `fmt.Printf()`

```
"Count=\"%!s(int=107)\"\nResults=\"[map[MATRICOLA:2 NOMEmy:value COGNOMEmy:value] map[MATRICOLA:7 NOMEmy:value COGNOMEmy:value] map[MATRICOLA:5 NOMEmy:value COGNOMEmy:value] map[MATRICOLA:6 NOMEmy:value COGNOMEmy:value]]\"\n"
```

https://play.golang.org/p/pRWUtRKikEh

```
    count := 107
    results := "[map[MATRICOLA:2 NOMEmy:value COGNOMEmy:value] map[MATRICOLA:7 NOMEmy:value COGNOMEmy:value] map[MATRICOLA:5 NOMEmy:value COGNOMEmy:value] map[MATRICOLA:6 NOMEmy:value COGNOMEmy:value]]"

    fmt.Printf("Count=%s\nResults=%s", count, results)
```

So if you would be able to change the print statement to `fmt.Printf("Count=%d\nResults=%s", count, results)` the output would be correct.
https://play.golang.org/p/g45_TiHMFsG

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I think you did not understand my goal. I would like what you printed as a string to end up in the Data struct, so without considering the count, I would like the part that is printed after Result to be transformed into map[string]string.

Comment: @bed It will not directly parse into `map[string]string` you should convert the string back to json and unmarshal the data.

Comment: I tried like this:
`split := strings.Split(vals, "\"")[1]

    splitend := strings.Split(split, "\"")[0]

    var ciao []map[string]string

    json.Unmarshal([]byte(splitend), &ciao)


    result := jsonmerge.Data{Count: count, Results: ciao}`

but not work, i have the string, but the map is not filled...

could you give me an example of what you said?

Comment: I think split is not a good idea, because that causes the performance issues. You should range over each character of your string. I still think that you are doing here too much work, because the bug is before your function. Because what you are doing here is to parse something which is not correct.